# how to solve apple sign redirection setting configuration in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apple-sign-in

`On your iPhone, go to Settings, then tap your name. Tap Password & Security > Apps Using Apple ID. Select the app or developer, then tap Stop Using Apple ID Try Again`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4TWN.jpg)

**Want this screen when tap on google sign in**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWJwe.png)